# Playing music using Asterisk-java

Tags: java, asterisk

hello all i want to know how to play music file to the user when he picks up my phone. in asterisk i can use A(X) in dial application. But i want to know how can i do the same using asterisk-java. which method will be useful for me.

Comment: I have configured the same project in different way. try this link
http://mobile-class.org/project.php

Answer (score 1):

Following are the methods from BaseAGIScript class which can be used to play sound files.

- `controlStreamFile` - Plays the sound file, user can interrupt by
  pressing any key.
- `getOption` - Plays the given sound file and waits
  for user option.
- `getData` - Plays the given sound file and waits for
  user enter data.

Answer (score 0):

This should provide the functionality you're looking for: [org.asteriskjava.fastagi.AgiChannel#streamFile](http://www.asterisk-java.org/1.0.0.M3/apidocs/org/asteriskjava/fastagi/AgiChannel.html#streamFile%28java.lang.String%29)